# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException using Simple 2.7.1 XML serializer on Android device <5

Tags: java, android, xml, serialization

Following code:

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister();
taskDefinition = serializer.read(TaskDefinition.class, file);
```

I receive the following error on android devices < 5.
Everything works perfectly on all devices running android 5 or higher.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "app.skynavigator.common.skynavlib.xml.RectangularZone" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]

The class RectangularZone exists and works for serializing the object.

This is the complete error message:

> 01-05 07:35:47.552 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "app.skynavigator.common.skynavlib.xml.RectangularZone" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.app.LoadedApk$WarningContextClassLoader.loadClass(LoadedApk.java:430)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.Loader.load(Loader.java:50)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.readValue(TreeStrategy.java:163)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.TreeStrategy.read(TreeStrategy.java:102)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Source.getOverride(Source.java:360)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getConversion(Factory.java:207)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Factory.getOverride(Factory.java:139)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ObjectFactory.getInstance(ObjectFactory.java:63)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:139)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.populate(CompositeList.java:175)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.read(CompositeList.java:120)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
>   01-05 07:35:47.562 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:543)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:521)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:426)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at app.skynavigator.common.skynavlib.parser.AfxParser.Import(AfxParser.java:27)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at app.skynavigator.common.skynavlib.files.TaskFile.ImportTask(TaskFile.java:45)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at app.skynavigator.common.skynavlib.Task.importTask(Task.java:59)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator.views.TaskListFragment.loadTask(TaskListFragment.java:95)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator.views.TaskListFragment.onListItemClick(TaskListFragment.java:84)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
>   01-05 07:35:47.572 28817-28817/app.skynavigator.android.skynavigator W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Are you using multidex? It could be a dex reference error. Post more code and more of the error log.

Comment: Can you explain this line---> Serializer serializer = new Persister();

Comment: @Jim: I tried both, presently I do not use multidex, but also with multidex, the issue still does exist.

Comment: @Amarbir: This line of code is the standard initializer for the Simple 2.7.1 XML serializer

Comment: @Christoph you are initializing Serializer with Persister...how come

Comment: @Amarbir: That's the common way for using Simple 2.7.1. You can find details under: http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#deserialize